# Create and assign Azure roles to Azure AD users automatically using Azure Cli though Powershell scripts

Tags: azure, powershell, roles

I am using a script to create Azure AD user, but when user login, it showing there are no any subscription for that users.
Now kindly let me know if you share the script to automate the process for assigning roles to that users automatically when he\she login in azure portal

Hoping for quick response

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assign roles exactly when user logs into the portal, but you can assign roles to the users once you create them:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId xxx -Scope '/subscriptions/%subscription_guid%' `
    -RoleDefinitionName Contributor (or Owner, Reader, etc)
```

You can use `-signInName` instead of the ObjectId, but since you just created the user you should have its ObjectId anyway

For CLI you can consult this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli
This one for powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell

Comment: Thanks c74356b41 & it will be appreciating response. But it showing error when we run New-AzRoleAssignment command as "It not recognized as Internal or external command"  ......Can you please suggest the solution for this Error

Comment: update your azure powershell or use `new-azurermroleassignment`